# Power of a function is (lebesgue) measurable implies function is lebesgue measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Measurable in my question = Lebesgue measurable

I was working on a problem stated as this:

Suppose that $f^2(x) $ is a measurable function defined on $\mathbb{R}^d$, and the set $\{f > 0 \}$ is measurable. Show that $f(x)$ is measurable.

I know that if you split the power of a measurable function $f^2$ into two sets, $\{f < \sqrt{a} \} \cup \{f > - \sqrt{a} \}$ if $a \geq 0$. So if $a < 0 $, you can't do this these sets are undefined? So how is $f^2$ measurable then? Supposedly this is an easy problem but I'm rather confused. I know $f^2$ measurable doesn't imply $f$ measurable but I don't see how if the set $\{f > 0 \}$ is measurable makes $f$ measurable.

As I was typing this I thought of a potential proof.

Since $\{f > 0 \}$ is measurable then its complement $\{f \leq 0 \}$ is measurable.
Now suppose $a > 0$. Then $f^2$ can be decomposed into two sets

$$\{f < \sqrt{a} \} \cup \{f > - \sqrt{a} \}$$.

But how can we guarantee that these two sets are measurable since we have no guarantee of the measurability of $f$?

Comment: I think the worry is that maybe if $S$ is a non measurable set, $f(x)=1$ for $x\in S$ and $f(x)=-1$ otherwise, so $f^2$ is measurable but $f$ is not.  But the condition that $\{x:f(x)>0\}$ is measurable rules out this kind of example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a\ge 0$, then
$$
\{f<a\} = \{f\le 0\}\cup\{0<f<a\}
=\{f\le 0\}^c\cup(\{f^2<a^2\}\cap\{f>0\})
$$
is measurable.
On the other hand, if $a<0$, then
$$
\{f<a\} = \{f\le0\}\cap\{f^2>a^2\}
$$
is measurable.
Therefore $f$ is measurable.